# Tomcat mod_proxy AJP static resources directory

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, httpd.conf, ajp

I am using httpd with tomcat using the following config:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
```

This works fine except my image links from tomcat do not work when the HTML renders:

```
<img src="/MyProject/img/image.jpg"/>
```

where as I would expect:

```
  <img src="/img/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Off topic. Belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: Your images are in MyProject or it is just a static content in apache?

Comment: @MartinStrejc They are in MyProject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image(s) is placed in tomcat at path /img/image.jpg that is context relative path, the absolute path is /MyProject/img/image.jpg for your tomcat, eventhough it is /img/image.jpg outside of the apache. You proxy / -> /MyProject so when you add the context name to the path 'MyProject', it really doesn't work as you mentioned.

**SOLUTION 1:**

Use **context relative paths** in tomcat

```
img/image.jpg
```

In this case you have to be careful about the requrested URI, e.g. /MyProject/page1/action1/ has its image relative path

```
../../img/image.jsp
```

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

Use **document root paths** with leading slash

```
/img/image.jpg
```

and define the element **base** with the document root ('**href**' attribute). Just be careful about link!

```
<head>
   <base href="http://www.mydomain.com/">
</head>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

---

**SOLUTION 3:**

Map the project to the **same URI in apache as in tomcat** (Personaly I use this solution as well because it is very easy, and I use a common word as a project/context name, e.g. 'web', 'site', etc.).

```
ProxyPass /MyProject ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
```

---

**SOLUTION 4:**

Use a **content filter** such as mod_proxy_html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html

NOTE: This solution is ever a bit slow (it doesn't matter witch filter you use)!

---

Be aware **PROXY CONFIGURATION!!!**

This is just about redirect etc., but you have a **wrong configuration of your ProxyPathReverse**!

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
ProxyPassReverse /MyProject http://www.mydomain.com/
```

see the full explanation
http://www.humboldt.co.uk/the-mystery-of-proxypassreverse/#more-131

read configuration examples
http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. Use `mod_html` to rewrite the links. This is slow, and an indication that you've done the wrong thing.
2. Issue a *redirect* from / to /MyProject, which you can do with a RewriteRule, or a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://<host>/MyProject/">` in `/index.html,` and change the `ProxyPass` directives to

   `ProxyPass /MyProject ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject`

so that proxying doesn't mess around with the URL paths. This is by far the better technique. You probably don't need the `ProxyPassReverse` directive at all, but if you do you should apply the same change.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tested this for accuracy (and AJP tends to short circuit things like rewrites in Apache making extra testing and tweaking almost mandatory). So with that little AJP-disclaimer you might try something along the lines of:

```
ProxyPass /MyProject ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
ProxyPassReverse /MyProject ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/MyProject
```

Just to try catching those incorrect image paths on the inbound. If that fails try toying with a trailing slash.